# is python ThreadPoolExecutor thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Like should I manually add locks when futures write the same file to guarantee they write it one by one?

- I mean the *concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor*
- And I know the java executor is thread safe

An Example:

```
def task():
    with open("somefile", "a") as fh:
        fh.write(part_of_data)
    do_something()
    with open("somefile", "a") as fh:
        fh.write(other_data)
```

In this example, I want to make sure each `other_data` is appended next to `part_of_data` when tasks are executed in ThreadPoorExecuter

I'm not sure the `with` statement is atomic operation, but if not, the executor should also guarantee the file is open and closed correctly

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to do, because for some things it is thread safe, for other things - not so much. Technically all of Python (CPython at least) is thread-safe as there is the dreaded GIL in the background preventing any two threads running at the same time, but that doesn't exclude the possibility of partial results and data corruption for non-atomic operations.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor will only run a single task at a time if configured with max_workers=1. Otherwise, tasks can run concurrently in different threads and you would need additional locking. This would contradict the idea of a pool of workers, because this can block one worker for the time the lock is held. And, BTW: The ThreadPoolExecutor in Java has the same behaviour in that regard.

Answer (score 13):

Here's my research after looking at the implementation [of the ThreadPoolExecutor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L108) in the standard library:

The `shutdown()` method is thread safe as it takes a lock before modifying shared state.

The `submit()` method is thread safe in only some of its operations, but in practice it won't matter. When you submit a new function to be executed in the thread pool your function is placed in an instance of the thread safe `queue.SimpleQueue`. Worker threads then block on this queue waiting to pop submitted functions off to execute them. Because the queue is thread safe the dispatching of submitted functions is thread safe which means that none of your submitted functions will be orphaned (not executed) or executed twice.

The part that is not thread safe is the internal `_adjust_thread_count()` method. It could be called from two different threads at the same time, creating a race where both threads see that `num_threads < self._max_workers` and both create new threads to fill up the thread pool. If this ever happens, though, it won't matter, as it just results in extra threads in the thread pool. That's hardly a problem to care about for most projects.

Comment: `_adjust_thread_count` method starts with `if self._idle_semaphore.acquire(timeout=0):` on python 3.8 at least.