# Will this cause a deadlock or a bad pattern?

Tags: python, multithreading, design-patterns, threadpool

Will the following way of using a thread pool cause a deadlock? Or is such a pattern not preferred? If so, what is the alternative.

Passing `pool` to a function that is run in a thread, which in turn invokes a function that is run the same pool.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


def bar():
    sleep(2)
    return 2


def foo(pool):
    sleep(2)
    my_list = [pool.submit(bar) for i in range(4)]
    return [i.result() for i in my_list]


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
my_list = [pool.submit(foo, pool) for i in range(2)]
for i in my_list:
    print(i.result())
```

Comment: Since your pool size is 10 and the maximum number of threads you create is also 10, I don't see why it would deadlock. Likewise, if you use a size less than 10, yes it will deadlock.

Comment: So the question here is really whether a ThreadPoolExecutor is, itself, thread safe and I do not know the answer to that. However, you can be sure that if a threaded function needs to run other threads, then construction of an additional  ThreadPoolExecutor within such a thread would surely be safest

Comment: @DavidK.Hess so if I submit more jobs to the pool than the threads it would deadlock?

Comment: @OlvinRoght "construction of an additional ThreadPoolExecutor" wouldn't this cause more threads to create than the limit I have? if my `foo` creates lets say a new thread pool of size 4, then each thread will end up creating a new pool of size 4 is it not?

Comment: @Valencia That is true but you could set your limit in the main program to 2 then 4 in foo(). In that way you'd limit the total number threads to 10. You might want to read this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286344/is-python-threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe

Comment: @OlvinRoght will check it out, also you mean 8 and not 10?

Comment: @Valencia I mean 10. You would have 2 foo() threads and each foo() could submit 4 bar() threads

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, it could deadlock if the pool were created with only two threads, but the program ran to completion when I did it using a pool with three threads. Three threads allows one worker for each of the two `foo()` calls, plus one more worker to execute the `bar()` calls. Nothing prevents the two `foo()` calls from submitting four tasks each to the pool—the task queue has no upper bound—and then the one remaining worker can process the `bar()` tasks, one-by-one. Each of the two `foo()` calls will be able to return as soon as all four of its `bar()` tasks have completed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow good analysis. So, I should say, it *can* deadlock at less than 10 but it may also succeed depending on race conditions between the threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a safe way to spawn a thread from within a thread that itself was initiated by ThreadPoolExecutor. This may not be necessary if ThreadPoolExecutor itself is thread-safe. The output shows how, in this case, there would be 10 concurrent threads.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


BAR_THREADS = 4
FOO_THREADS = 2

def bar(_):
    print('Running bar')
    sleep(1)

def foo(_):
    print('Running foo')
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=BAR_THREADS) as executor:
        executor.map(bar, range(BAR_THREADS))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=FOO_THREADS) as executor:
    executor.map(foo, range(FOO_THREADS))

print('Done')
```

**Output:**

```
Running foo
Running foo
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Running bar
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

> Will the following way of using a thread pool cause a deadlock? ... If so, what is the alternative?

One alternative would be to use a thread pool that does not have a hard limit on the number of workers. Unfortunately, the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` class is not so sophisticated. You either would have to write your own, or else find one provided by a third party. (I'm not a big-time Python programmer, so I don't know of one off-hand.)

A naive alternative thread-pool might create a new worker any time `submit()` was called and all of the existing workers were busy. On the other hand, that could make it easy for you to run the program out of memory by creating too many threads. A slightly more sophisticated thread pool might also kill off a worker if too many other workers were idle at the moment when the worker completed its task.

More sophisticated strategies are possible, but you might have to think more deeply about the needs and patterns-of-use of the application before writing the code.